# VisualStudio Autocomplete is disabled when inside a Unity Conditional Compliation region

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

See the following code snippet:

```
    #if UNITY_EDITOR
            _costLabel.text = TMPTags.GetCostString(2000, CostType.Prestige);
#else
            _costLabel.text = TMPTags.GetCostString(GetCost(out CostType costType), costType);
#endif
```

The part in the #else clause is grayed out and autocomplete doesn't work. Is there anyway to enable VisualStudio's autocomplete inside the #else clause as well?

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 version 17.6.

Screenshot for a better visualization:

[image]

Comment: write the lines of code, then use the defines to section it out

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is deliberate since the grayed out code won't be compiled

Comment: Thanks but any idea if there's an alternative if I don't want to manually remove the sections and I want to override the default behavior?

Comment: Temporarily move the greyed out line outside of the #else part.